# if $X$ is a vector field how can I find $Y$ such that $[X,Y]=0$?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-analysis

Suppose I am given a holomorphic vector field $X$ over a complex manifold $M$. To simplify this we can suppose that $X$ is a holomorphic vector field in $\mathbb{C}^n$ for $n=2$ or $n=3$. How can I determine another vector field (non-colinear with $X$) such that their Lie Bracker $[X,Y]$=0? I am trying to do this without applying the vector field $[X,Y]$ to an arbitrary $f$ and working with coordinates and a lot of derivatives.

Should this problem be too complicated (and I think it is) we should probably stick with polynomial vector fields (or even with the homogeneous polynomials ones, although these have already been classificated here: [link](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~deserti/review/review26.pdf&ei=DuutUd3TOJD69gSfqYHwBA&usg=AFQjCNHUTCHZKareJMfq05WObuzMP5lymA&sig2=hBml4U2aDrvniu3ikStaNA&bvm=bv.47244034,d.eWU&cad=rja) in dimension two).

I am hopeful that there is something done in this sense in some Lie Group theory literature before. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gustavo, this probably doesn't make you happy, but you need a vector field that's invariant under the flow of $X$. So pick an arbitrary hyperplane $H$ transverse to $X_0=X(0)\in\mathbb C^n$, and let $Y_0\in \mathbb C^n$ be arbitrary. Set $Y(p)=Y_0$ at points $p\in H$. 
Let $\phi_t$ be the $X$-flow, and take $Y(\phi_t(p)) = (\phi_t)_{*p}Y_0$. Does this work?

Comment: It helps, but I guess that if $Y(\phi_t(p)) = (\phi_t)_{*p}Y_0$ has a solution (as a differential equation I guess), it is only local and does not solve the problem if I'm trying to find a global $Y$. :(

Comment: There may be topological/homological obstructions if you're trying to be global. After all, even in the smooth category, you need $\chi(M)=0$ just to have one nonvanishing vector field, and you need $c_{n-1}(TM)=0$ to have two everywhere linearly independent vector fields.

Comment: What are those notations?

Comment: Oh, Euler characteristic (which is the top Chern class of the tangent bundle) and the next-to-top Chern class, $c_{n-1}$.

Comment: do you mind pointing me to any reference where I can find some introductions to the things you mentioned?

Comment: @Gustavo: Probably the best source for you would be Griffiths and Harris (unless you want to come audit my graduate geometry class this fall :)). You might also enjoy Chern's seminal paper: http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789812812834_0011